# Изменение работы Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Нужно изменить логику авторизации и аутентификации, Spring Security по умолчанию использует во время поиска первичный ключ username, мне же необходимо, чтобы первичный ключ был user_id, т.к. в приложении должна быть возможность смены username. Подскажите, где посмотреть примеры, то что нагуглил, запустить не удалось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переопределить стандартную реализацию, о которой вы говорите, в Spring Security  просто. Создайте свой класс для пользователя приложения от `UserDetails`:

```
public class User implements UserDetails {

    private Long userID;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String fullName;
    private String email;
    private List<UserRole> authorities;

    // ... getters, setters

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

}

public class UserRole implements GrantedAuthority {

    private Long userRoleID;
    private String authority;

    // ... getters, setters

}
```

Сервис

```
@Service("myDatabaseUserService")
public class DatabaseUserService implements UserDetailsService {

    private UserDao userDao;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myUserDao")
    public void setUserDao(UserDao userDao) {
        this.userDao = userDao;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        // получаем пользователя из базы данных
        User user = userDao.getUserByUsername(userName);
        if ( user == null ) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User with name " + userName + " not found");
        }
        return user;
    }

}
```

Конфигурация

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myDatabaseUserService")
    private UserDetailsService databaseUserService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // назначаем Spring Security кастомный UserDetailsService
        auth.userDetailsService(databaseUserService);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Класс `UserDao`, который получает пользователя из базы данных - напишите самостоятельно, на основании того что вы используете в приложении: **JDBC**, **Spring JdbcTemplate**, **SpringData**, **JPA** или что-то еще.

Фреймворку не важно как у вас устроена база данных, и какие поля там уникальные, пишите свою реализацию, используя стандартные интерфейсы.

Comment: не могу понять, тогда где мы будем писать сам новый запрос?

Comment: а понял, UserDao

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ